# Why is electric-indent-mode adding extra indentation after pressing return twice in org source blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, indentation, electric-indent

When I try to write code in source block in Org mode, pressing return once acts as expected while hitting it a second time increases the indentation to two levels if it's currently less than that. Here's an example of how the cursor moves when I press return at various initial indentation levels:

```
#+begin_src python
def my_function():
    # Each "." shows where the cursor goes after pressing RET.
    .
        .
        .
        .
        

    def internal_function():
        # Same thing from here.
        .
        .
        .
        .
        
        def double_internal_function():
            # Same thing from here.
            .
            .
            .
            .
            
        
# Same thing from here.
.
        .
        .
        .

#+end_src
```

It is `(org-return electric-indent-mode)` that is being called when I press return, and I'm able to reproduce this behavior by calling this myself. Some other function calls that don't exhibit the same behavior are `(org-return-and-maybe-indent)`, `(org-return)`, `(org-newline-and-indent)`, and `(newline-and-indent)`. If I disable `electric-indent-mode`, then the second return eliminates all indentation entirely. Ideally, I would want repeatedly pressing return to maintain the same indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable: `org-adapt-indentation` to off.

Comment: This is already `nil` for me when I see this behavior.

Comment: Share your .emacs without the irrelevant portions, do include the python mode configurations.  Does this happen in python mode buffers also or just in org source blacks ?  Does this happen in any other programming modes ?